# What could a definition of characteristic time be when dealing with heat transfer?

Tags: thermodynamics

Is there an actual definition of characteristic time? When dealing with heat transfer for instance convective heat transfer between a naked flame and a fluid in a glass bulb, can characteristic time be defined as: the time taken to for the centre of the fluids temperature to be a certain percentage of its surface temperature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One commonly used definition is in the case of the solution of [Newton's Law of Cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Mathematical_formulation_of_Newton's_law) (or Heating), where one approach uses dimensionless groups.

The solution is, with $\tau$ the *characteristic time*:

$$\ln\Theta=-\frac{t}{\tau}$$
where:
$$\Theta =\frac{T(t)-T_{env}}{T_0-T_{env}}\text{  and  } \frac{1}{\tau}=\frac{hA}{mc_p}$$

with:

- $h$ is the heat transfer coefficient
- $A$ is the heat transfer surface area
- $T(t)$ is the temperature of the object's surface, evolving in time $t$
- $T_{env}$ is the temperature of the environment; i.e. the temperature suitably far from the surface
- $m$ is object's mass and $c_p$ its specific heat capacity.

Defined that way the characteristic time is:

$$\boxed{\tau=\frac{mc_p}{hA}}$$

> can characteristic time be defined as: the time taken to for the
>   centre of the fluids temperature to be a certain percentage of its
>   surface temperature.

No, that's not really how its use is intended.

**Reference:** [A Heat Transfer Textbook](https://ahtt.mit.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/AHTTv500.pdf) (Lienhard & Lienhard)

Comment: There is some relationship between characteristic time and how close you are to steady state or equilibrium though, isn't there?  It's been years since I learned it, but I remember it being similar to the [RC time constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant) which sounds _kinda_ like what OP's teacher was trying to get at.

Comment: Yes, I guess you could make that connection. High CT means slower cooling e.g., so it kind of reflects the cooling time.

Comment: Brilliant guys! I couldnt thank you enough. Im just starting my journey. I hope one day to have the vast knowledge of some people on here.

Comment: You're welcome.